# How do I avoid "dimnames must be a list"-error when creating a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm brushing up on my linear algebra skills. Since my notebook is getting messy I'm trying to create my matrices in R. It is my hope that then I'll manage to avoid random errors.

I try to create a matrix with three rows and six columns:

```
matrix(
    c(2,2,1,1,0,0),
    c(1,3,2,0,1,0), 
    c(1,3,6,0,0,1),
    nrow=3,
    ncol=6)
```

I then get an error message stating that:

```
Error in matrix(c(2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0), c(1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0), c(1, 3, 6, 0,  : 
  'dimnames' must be a list
```

I'm not sure I understand the hickup. I have specified my three rows and there's nothing in the help section claiming a need for naming anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't say "dimnames must be named”, it says "'dimnames' must be a list". It happens because you provide three `c()` objects in arguments, and the function expects only the first as an input data. Just wrap in one `c()`:

```
matrix(
c(   c(2,2,1,1,0,0),
    c(1,3,2,0,1,0), 
    c(1,3,6,0,0,1) 
),
    nrow=3,
    ncol=6)
```

Or put all numbers in a single `c()` from the very beginning. And you actually don't need to indicate both `nrow` and `ncol`, one is enough:

```
matrix(
c(2,2,1,1,0,0,
 1,3,2,0,1,0, 
 1,3,6,0,0,1),
  nrow=3)
```

Comment: This is how I ended up solving the problem, although I also have to set the byrow argument to TRUE in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to create matrices is to just bind your vectors:

```
rbind(
  c(2,2,1,1,0,0),
  c(1,3,2,0,1,0), 
  c(1,3,6,0,0,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rbind` to row-bind a series of vectors, or feed a *single* vector to the `matrix` function. Note that if you choose option 2, you need to set `byrow=TRUE` because `matrix` is column major by default.

```r
rbind(c(2,2,1,1,0,0),
      c(1,3,2,0,1,0), 
      c(1,3,6,0,0,1))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    2    2    1    1    0    0
#> [2,]    1    3    2    0    1    0
#> [3,]    1    3    6    0    0    1

matrix(
    c(2,2,1,1,0,0,
      1,3,2,0,1,0, 
      1,3,6,0,0,1),
    nrow=3,
    ncol=6,
    byrow=TRUE)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    2    2    1    1    0    0
#> [2,]    1    3    2    0    1    0
#> [3,]    1    3    6    0    0    1
```